# Tool for todo notes and lists for linux which allows tagging

Tags: software-rec

I am looking for a handy (offline) tool to manage todo-notes and lists on linux. As a necessary requirement it should be possible to assign tags and sort, filter and search for tags. It should support web-links.

Nice to have (but not neccessary):

- mark progress of the item
- mark importance
- have a calendar to easily insert dates for deadlines for example
- some rudimentary versioning control system for the lists
- should be able to handle images or even video embeddings
- tables
- support for math-formulas
- should be keyboard friendly

Any suggestions?

I do not have any restricion whether is has to have a GUI or not, it may something which runs in a browser, it may have an ordinary GUI, or just an ncurses interface, it's important that it's handy. *But there is one restriction*: It should not be an applet which works only together with gnome-panel or something like that (I don't use a panel or tray bar).

Comment: [`remind`](http://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/remind) is the best command-line calendar application for Linux that I know of (and use).  It uses a plain text file calendar format, with a rather powerful albeit domain-specific scripting language that can express very complex rules for recurring events.  It is mostly calendar and not so much todo list manager, but as a calendar it's hard to beat.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take a look at [taskwarrior](http://taskwarrior.org/)! Visit the [tutorial](http://taskwarrior.org/projects/taskwarrior/wiki/Tutorial) to learn about its capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I like such command line tools and I didn't knew it.

Comment: I tried a lot, devtodo is my favorite. It allows me to have separated todo lists for every project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Getting Things GNOME](http://gtg.fritalk.com/) (abbreviated GTG). It supports tagging tasks with multiple tags and allows you to run queries based on tags.

For example, `!not @money !not @1` will show tasks that aren't money related or have an high priority.

I use the @1 tag for high-priority tasks, @2 for medium-priority tasks and @3 for low-priority tasks, but you are free to choose a different tagging system for priority.

GTG has a build in calendar for selecting start/due dates.

At the moment you cannot insert tables, images, videos or math formulas, but links are automatically created when you insert one.

At the end of this month a new version of GTG will be released, but I suggest you to try the current version (0.2.9) which is already really good (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Zim Desktop Wiki](http://www.zim-wiki.org/) and [TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org/). Both support Linux and provide tagging.

I used Zim since a few years, it is very keyboard friendly (you can type markup and it will beautify on-the-fly, and there are lots of shortcuts, I never use the toolbars), and it supports all the other optional items you cited, except video embedding (you can attach videos to a note, or any other filetype, but it won't be embedded visually, you will have to click on it to see it, but you can link to it in a note as a local relative URL).

TagSpaces is a new contender and it is more oriented towards document managing, with a very clear focus on tagging to sort and manage quickly your notes and documents. I did not use it yet so I don't know if it fits your optional requests, but it something you should try.

Both are OpenSource and quite mature (Zim is the most mature, it's out there since almost a decade, but TagSpaces has a strong development process, it's maturing very quickly).